# SQL Server : cumulative data for 10 days

Tags: sql-server

Existing query:

```
DECLARE @symbol1 VARCHAR(50) = 'D',
        @symbol2 VARCHAR(50) = 'N',
        @barDurationSeconds INT = 60,
        @daysOfData INT = 1 // it gets me one day and I want it for 10 days

DECLARE @bars INT = DATEDIFF(second, '2000-01-01 9:30', '2000-01-01 16:00') / @barDurationSeconds * @daysOfData;

WITH t AS
(
    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(second, '2000-01-01', time)/ @barDurationSeconds startOfBar,
        last,
        time,
        symbol
    FROM
        ticks (nolock)
    WHERE
        symbol IN (@symbol1, @symbol2)
        AND time < DATEADD(second, 5, GETDATE())
        AND '9:30' <= CAST(time AS TIME) 
        AND CAST(time AS TIME) <= '16:00'
), m as 
(
    SELECT
        (a.last + b.last) / 2 Last,
        a.startOfBar, 
        a.time
    FROM
        (SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.Symbol = @symbol1) a
    JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.Symbol = @symbol2) b ON a.time = b.time
), r AS 
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY startofbar ORDER BY time DESC) r
    FROM
        m
)
SELECT TOP (@bars)
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), DATEADD(second, startofbar * @barDurationSeconds, '2000-01-01'), 126) + 'Z' Time,
    last [Close],
    AVG([last]) OVER (ORDER BY startofbar DESC rows between current row and 20 following) SMAS,  
    SUM((r.last / 1.5)) OVER (ORDER BY startofbar DESC) addclose 
FROM
    r
WHERE
    r = 1
ORDER BY
    startofbar DESC
```

This returns an output something like this:

```
    2018-06-15T10:13:00Z    -12020805.50000000000   -12363199.40476190476   -12020805.50000000000
    2018-06-15T10:12:00Z    -11987902.00000000000   -12440169.00000000000   -24008707.50000000000
    2018-06-15T10:11:00Z    -11969724.50000000000   -12546814.04761904761   -35978432.00000000000
    2018-06-15T10:10:00Z    -11904352.00000000000   -12637389.83333333333   -47882784.00000000000
    2018-06-15T10:09:00Z    -11525636.00000000000   -12698771.90476190476   -59408420.00000000000
    2018-06-15T10:08:00Z    -11669141.00000000000   -12812096.64285714285   -71077561.00000000000
    2018-06-15T10:07:00Z    -11905796.00000000000   -12921254.45238095238   -82983357.00000000000
    2018-06-15T10:06:00Z    -11739935.50000000000   -13002297.35714285714   -94723292.50000000000
    2018-06-15T10:05:00Z    -12324505.50000000000   -13088795.45238095238   -107047798.00000000000
    2018-06-15T10:04:00Z    -12431126.50000000000   -13137961.54761904761   -119478924.50000000000
```

So it always shows 390 rows i.e between 9:30 to 16:00 hours of today or yesterday (combined together there would be 390 rows).

Required output: this shows data for a day but now I want a cumulative data for last 10 days. Please advise how can I do that.

Edit:
I have data for last 6 months data and with new requirement it should return 10 rows instead of 390

Comment: I have suspicion that you have data only for 2 days. Because I see intention to display more: `@daysOfData int = 5`. And nowhere I see another limit. `time < dateadd(second, 5, getdate())` - will grab all existing data. Are you sure that you have more than 2 days of data?

Comment: Ingaz - thank you for taking time to check my query. Sorry,  the existing query @daysOfData has "1" as parameter.So it shows only 390 rows wherein today or till yertday the data is retreived. And it reterive data for every minute. I want it for 10 days so there should be 10 records.